# Does this code pass the app store?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I need to know if user has certain apps on his iphone device

I have this code

```
BOOL isInstalled = [[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] applicationIsInstalled:@"com.app.identifier"];

if (isInstalled) {
    // app is installed }
else {
    // app is not installed
}
```

which in theory does the job

the question is in practice, does it pass the app store?
can i use the `"LSApplicationWorkspace"` class ?

Comment: Short and painless: No. `applicationIsInstalled` seems to be private API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2):

No.

All applications referencing private APIs and even **undocumented** APIs are not allowed.