# What alternatives are there to +[LSApplicationWorkspace defaultWorkspace] and -allApplications?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that uses
`LSApplicationWorkspace`'s `+defaultWorkspace` and `-allApplications`, but I can't use these on the App Store.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Are you asking how to appeal this with Apple (not likely to work), or for other functions you can use instead?

Comment: LSApplicationWorkspace is a private API: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35807764/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33854183/1187415 – Why do you need it and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: App Store policy/review rejections are off topic here, so I've edited your question to focus on the technical aspect.

Answer (score 1):

> What alternatives do I have?

If you are using `LSApplicationWorkspace` to detect what applications are installed? None.

Apple treats the list of installed applications as private, and have made deliberate changes to other APIs in the past to keep that information private. (For instance, [iOS 9 applied limits to `canOpenURL:` to prevent it from being used to detect installed applications](https://cromulentlabs.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/explanation-of-canopenurl-changes-in-ios-9/).)

If you need to detect other *specific* applications, and those applications implement custom URL schemes, you can still use `canOpenURL:` to check for those. However, you will need to declare these URL schemes ahead of time in your `Info.plist`, and you cannot detect applications which do not handle unique URL schemes.